# Why is this PHP code not opening or writing to a file?

Tags: php

I am using PHP to write information to a text file. I have used this code before, and it worked, but in a new project, it is not working.

I think the problem might be a permissions issue. The server is Ubuntu.

```
$message = "RESULTS = " . $data . "\n";
$fh = fopen("test.txt", 'a'); //open file and create if does not exist
fwrite($fh, "\n\n******* " . date('l, F j, Y (g:i A)') . " *********\n\n"); //Just for spacing in log file
fwrite($fh, $message); //write data
fclose($fh); //close file
```

When I debug using Netbeans, `fopen()` returns a boolean value of `0`, which I take to means it failed, but I'm not sure what the reason is.

Is there anything wrong with the code above? If not, what permissions settings do I need on the directories or files involved to ensure I'm not getting blocked by a permission setting?

Is there anything else I should be looking for?

Comment: You have to add write permissions to the folder.

Comment: it returns a boolean value of `false`. Apart from that, it also issues a warning level notification, which you might be able to catch or show by setting the appropriate debugging options. [PHP: How to show warnings](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Comment: On Ubuntu, `/` is the root folder. I assume you don't have writing permissions to it

Comment: @Reeno, sorry, that was a typo. I've corrected the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your directory 
add dot-slash (./) at the beginning of your directory

```
$fh = fopen("./test.txt",'a'); //open file and create if does not exist
```

Comment: This worked, but it puzzles me a little. I don't remember having to do this before the first time I used the code in a previous project. Can you add a little explanation about why the `./` is needed?

Comment: check this link, read filename section
http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu ,

for a single file :

```
sudo chmod  777 /var/www/your-path/file.txt
```

for a directory

```
  sudo  chmod -R 777 /var/www/your-path
```